# Java - Change Object Attribute From Other Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming

I am writing simple client-server program. The problem, that I have faced is following: I am sending an object from client to server and I start new thread for every object sent to server.

I need to get data from deserialized object and update server object attribute with this data. How can I do that?

This is my server code:

```
...

// Property to be updated
private FieldMap fieldMap = new FieldMap();
public void startServer() {
    try {
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
        (new Thread(this)).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    running = false;
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    running = true;
    while (running) {
        try {
            this.setChanged();
            this.notifyObservers();
            System.out.println("Listening for a connection");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputHandler inputHandler = new InputHandler(socket, fieldMap);
            (new Thread(inputHandler)).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

...
```

This is listener object code:

```
public class InputHandler implements Runnable {

     private Socket socket;
     private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
     private FieldMap map;

     InputHandler(Socket socket, FieldMap map) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        this.map = map;
     }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Lemming lemming = (Lemming) objectInputStream.readObject();
            lemming.getFieldMap().union(map);
            map = lemming.getFieldMap();
            System.out.println(lemming);
            (new Thread(lemming)).start();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                 objectInputStream.close();
                 socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to update `fieldMap` from `InputHandler`?

Comment: What do you mean? `InputHandler` already has a reference to the `FieldMap` passed to it in the constructor. It can just update the map using that reference. Are you asking about the thread safety aspects of updating `FieldMap` from several threads?

Answer (score 0):

You need some methods like in java.uitl.Map

```
fieldMap.clear()
fieldMap.putAll(otherFieldMap)
```